Is this pex bent too tightly?
I'm putting in a 60 inch vanity, and I'm trying to make sure that the rough in plumbing fits in the base cabinet. I had to bend the pex more than I was comfortable with. There are no leaks, so it's okay for now. I just want to make sure this is okay from someone who actually knows what they are doing.


You're asking about the "minimum bend radius" for PEX pipe (knowing what term to search for is most of the battle, these days!). The question PEX minimum radius of curvature and its answer might have the information you're after.

Note that the PEX itself really isn't bending that much.  Looks like there's a 90 deg elbow (brass?).

Your PEX is fine.
PEX expands a lot when hot water runs through it, its thermal expansion is much higher than copper. The elbow on the left will move up and down a little bit every time someone takes a shower. So the red horizontal section will bend up and down slightly every time.

So while the red horizontal pipe looks like it's too long and weird, this is exactly what's needed to provide wiggle room for thermal expansion. Don't change anything, there's no need to fasten it.
There is no issue with bend radius in your installation, it's fine. These issues occur when trying to bend PEX at right angles in tight corners. If you do that you can collapse the pipe. Here's an example picture:

That pipe is dead and the segment with the kink should be cut and replaced. If you want to bend PEX at right angles, either use elbows like you did, or get some of these guides:


Your pex is fine.  There is nothing to worry about.
I may have made the horizontal pieces a bit shorter, just because I like clean 90deg. bends, but what you have done is perfectly fine.
Give yourself some credit and a pat on the back.

Never used PEX before—it is worthwhile to fasten it down at changes of direction (like the 90s)?

It's not necessary, but admittedly, I have placed blocking between studs and anchored the pipe as a measure to prevent any rattling.
